# Bootstrap error and the images not loading on ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bootstrapping

While testing my project on my iOS device, there was a bootstrap error which got resolved on restarting the device and deleting the app. But now when I try to load the app on the device the images do not load up! I tried everything regarding images not loading up but nothing works! 
To solve this I had to port the full project into a NEW xcode project, then it worked! I was wondering if there is a easier solution to it!

Thanx in advance!

**SOLUTION** It was an XCODE problem! It had started showing me some hilarious errors like UIKIT , FOUNDATION FRAMEWORK not found! I updated my lion to 10.7.4 and Xcode to 4.4 and it works fine now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION It was an XCODE problem! It had started showing me some hilarious errors like UIKIT , FOUNDATION FRAMEWORK not found! I updated my lion to 10.7.4 and Xcode to 4.4 and it works fine now! :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure your images are added to the project target. sometimes you'll see the resources but that doesnt mean that they are attached to the target. to check this better go to the **summary** tab after clicking on project. in **buildPhases** under **copyBundleResources** check if the images are listed.

when you add any images to xCode project make sure **addToTarget** is checked.

Happy Coding..

Comment: Thank you Alex for your answer! But i guess it was a xcode problem! It had started showing me some hilarious errors like UIKIT , FOUNDATION FRAMEWORK not found! I updated my lion to 10.7.4 and Xcode to 4.4 and it works fine now!

Comment: yes this happenes sometimes. In most of my cases I would prefer to quit and restart mac. and even if it gives you a hard time better just reinstall it caz it. there might be corrupted sdk in order to update your version.